# Consume power usage clarification

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

The rulebook says in the "Consume" section:

> Each consume power can be used only once in a consume phase. Some powers allow multiple goods, “up to” some number, to be discarded, with each good producing an effect. Such powers must be fully used, if possible, when invoked.
>
> > Thus, a player with a tableau containing three novelty goods, New
> >     Vinland, and Free Trade Association, cannot consume two goods
> >     using FTA’s power (to consume up to 3 novelty goods for 1 VP
> >     and a card apiece) and then, based on the cards received, decide
> >     to consume the third novelty good using New Vinland’s power (to
> >     consume a good for two

[image][image]

Let's consider a slighty modified example: The player has a tableau containing *two* novelty goods, New Vinland, and Free Trade Association. Since FTA power cannot be fully used because the player does not have three novelty goods, the player decide to use it to consume just one novelty good. The rules above do not forbid that. Then the player uses the New Vinland power for the remaining novelty good.

If the rules intention was to forbid that, they would say instead of "Such powers must be fully used, if possible, when invoked" something to the effect "Such powers must consume as many matching goods as the player has, up to the specified number".

Did I get this right? I'd like an authorative source, please.

Comment: You got it wrong. The card itself says "discard UP TO 3 novelty goods...", which when combined with the quoted rule means that you have to discard/consume as many as possible.

Comment: Also, the quoted example says if you have three you can't [just] consume two! I get what you're trying to do, from a gameplay perspective, but you have to find another way to do it. As another player said on BGG: "you may choose the order that you use your consume powers which can result in having active consume powers and goods remaining on planets, due to the powers having a restrictive type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You are reading too much into this rule. “Fully used if possible” can also be understood as “used as much as possible”.

Now, let's assume your interpretation is the correct one. Using the boardstate you described minus the New Vinland. You could consume only one good (or even 0 by arguing that it is not more than 3), which is against the spirit of the rules (you must consume as much as possible).

So, while I do not have an authorative source, I can say that your interpretation is not the intended one.

Comment: To the extent that the app is authoritative, my 3000+ plays require you to consume as many goods as possible.

Comment: (that is, if the *rule book* isn't authoritative enough!)

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 the rule book is. And it says the opposite to what you are saying. I guess, it's a case of bad wording on the rulebook part. Thank you for contributing.